# MySQL: Multiple Running Totals from Different Subqueries

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

When I run a single query using the following formula to have the first column give back the month/year, the second give back the number of people signing per month, and the third give back the running total of signers, it works great:

```
SET @runtot1:=0;
SELECT
   1rt.MONTH,
   1rt.1signed,
   (@runtot1 := @runtot1 + 1rt.1signed) AS 1rt
FROM 
   (SELECT
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
       IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.surveyid = 791796 THEN s.id ELSE NULL END),0) AS 1signed
    FROM  table1 s
    JOIN table2 m ON s.id = m.id AND m.current = "Yes"
    WHERE STR_TO_DATE(s.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y') > '2015-03-01'
    GROUP  BY MONTH
    ORDER  BY MONTH) AS 1rt
```

With the query above, I get the following results table, which would be exactly what I want if I only needed to count one thing:

```
MONTH   1signed 1rt
2015-03 0       0
2015-04 1       1
2015-05 0       1
2015-08 1       2
2015-10 1       3
2015-11 1       4
2016-01 0       4
2016-02 0       4
```

But I can't figure out how to do that with multiple subqueries since I need this to happen for multiple columns at the same time. For example, I was attempting things like this ([which doesn't work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26494/38)):

```
SET @runtot1:=0;
SET @runtot2:=0;
select 
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s1.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
  t1.1signed,
  (@runtot1 := @runtot1 + t1.1signed) AS 1rt,
  t2.2signed,
  (@runtot2 := @runtot2 + t2.2signed) AS 2rt
from
    (select 
     DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
     IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.surveyid = 791796 THEN s.id ELSE NULL END),0) AS 1signed
     from table1 s 
     left join table2 m ON m.id = s.id
     where m.current = "Yes"
     GROUP BY MONTH
     ORDER BY MONTH) as T1,
     (select 
     DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
     IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.surveyid = 846346 THEN s.id ELSE NULL END),0) AS 2signed
     from table1 s 
     left join table2 m ON m.id = s.id
     where m.current = "Yes"
     GROUP BY MONTH
     ORDER BY MONTH) as T2,
     table1 s1
LEFT JOIN table2 m1 ON m1.id = s1.id AND m1.current = "Yes"
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(s1.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y') > '2015-03-01'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s1.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s1.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m')
```

That blew up my results badly -- I also tried LEFT JOINs to get those two next each other, but that didn't work either.

Here's a **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26494/1)** with a few values with the query at the top that works, but not the query needed to look like the idea below.

If the multiple subquery version of the code worked, below would be the ideal end-result:

```
MONTH   1signed 1rt 2signed 2rt
2015-03 0       0   1       1
2015-04 1       1   0       1
2015-05 0       1   1       2
2015-08 1       2   0       2
2015-10 1       3   0       2
2015-11 1       4   0       2
2016-01 0       4   0       2
2016-02 0       4   1       3
```

Just trying to figure out a way to get counts by month and rolling totals since March 2015 for two different survey questions using the same query. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Strawberry    Sorry -- I added some examples of what they look like. I Hope that helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102735/discussion-between-ryan-and-strawberry).

Comment: So, to recap, given the data set provided in the update sqlfiddle, and only the data set provided in the updated sqlfiddle, what should the desired result set look like?

Comment: @Strawberry    A non-SQL Fiddle example is provided in the question above. But in the SQL Fiddle example, it would be the exact result that my original query produces for 1signed (counts by month) and 1rt (running total) based on surveyid 791796 -- and it would also have two additional columns next to it that work exactly the same way called 2signed and 2rt based on surveyid 846346. Based on the example I gave in the SQL Fiddle, the running total for 2rt should end up being 4.

Comment: You're not making this easy for us, are you?

Comment: @Strawberry    Everything is now in line with the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26494/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're after something like this...

The data set:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
( id INT NOT NULL
, date_contacted DATE NOT NULL
, survey_id INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(id,survey_id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;

CREATE TABLE table2
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,is_current TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1,"2015-03-05",846346),
(2,"2015-04-15",791796),
(2,"2015-05-04",846346),
(3,"2015-06-07",791796),
(3,"2015-06-08",846346),
(4,"2015-08-02",791796),
(5,"2015-10-15",791796),
(6,"2015-11-25",791796),
(6,"2016-01-02", 11235),
(6,"2016-02-06",846346);

INSERT INTO table2 (id,is_current) VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,0),
(4,1),
(5,1),
(6,1);
```

The query:

```
SELECT x.*
     , @a:=@a+a rt_a
     , @b:=@b+b rt_b
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_contacted,'%Y-%m') month
            , SUM(survey_id = 791796) a
            , SUM(survey_id = 846346) b
         FROM table1 x 
         JOIN table2 y 
           ON y.id = x.id 
        WHERE y.is_current = 1
        GROUP 
           BY month
     ) x
  JOIN (SELECT @a:=0,@b:=0) vars
 ORDER 
    BY month;
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| month   | a    | b    | rt_a | rt_b |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| 2015-03 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    1 |
| 2015-04 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |
| 2015-05 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    2 |
| 2015-08 |    1 |    0 |    2 |    2 |
| 2015-10 |    1 |    0 |    3 |    2 |
| 2015-11 |    1 |    0 |    4 |    2 |
| 2016-01 |    0 |    0 |    4 |    2 |
| 2016-02 |    0 |    1 |    4 |    3 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt was actually pretty close. I just got rid of S1 and joined the two subqueries together on their MONTH columns:

```
SET @runtot1:=0;
SET @runtot2:=0;
select 
  T1.MONTH,
  t1.1signed,
  (@runtot1 := @runtot1 + t1.1signed) AS 1rt,
  t2.2signed,
  (@runtot2 := @runtot2 + t2.2signed) AS 2rt
from
    (select 
     DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
     IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.surveyid = 791796 THEN s.id ELSE NULL END),0) AS 1signed
     from table1 s 
     left join table2 m ON m.id = s.id
     where m.current = "Yes" and STR_TO_DATE(s.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y') > '2015-03-01'
     GROUP BY MONTH
     ORDER BY MONTH) as T1,
     (select 
     DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
     IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.surveyid = 846346 THEN s.id ELSE NULL END),0) AS 2signed
     from table1 s 
     left join table2 m ON m.id = s.id
     where m.current = "Yes" and STR_TO_DATE(s.datecontacted,'%m/%d/%Y') > '2015-03-01'
     GROUP BY MONTH
     ORDER BY MONTH) as T2
WHERE 
T1.MONTH=T2.MONTH
GROUP BY T1.MONTH
ORDER BY T1.MONTH
```

I haven't tested Strawberry's solution, which looks more elegant. But I thought you'd like to know that your approach (solving the running totals individually, then joining the results together) would have worked too.